# PowerShell ConfigurationElement and static typing

Tags: c#, powershell, static-typing

I'm writing some PowerShell scripts with that make use of the WebAdministration module. In the ISE, if a variable type is known, the ISE Script Pane usually provides intellisense help.

However, (assuming there's at least 1 website on my box), what is the type of the following?

```
$w = (Get-Website)[0];
```

Get-Member gives the type as `Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement#site`

What does the `#` mean?

Can I strongly type this variable so that the Script Pane provides the "same level" of intellisense help as the Console does? E.g. the Console knows that `$w` has a `Start()` method, but the Script Pane does not.

The analogous .Net framework type is presumably [Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.site%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)